# unable to load page defined path in config passing id in url codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have defined the path of url in codeigniter like

```
$route['read_inquiry'] = 'dashboard/read_inquiry/';
```

now i have passed the id in url, the page gives error that no page found.
If i remove route path and pass the controller name along with method in url like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/read_inquiry').'/'.$this -> encryption -> encrypt('1'); ?>">ABC</a>
```

then it shows the page. What to do, how to load page while assigning the path in route.

Comment: Check @Vickel answer. Your `read_inquiry($param)` method has to expect parameter. Check code in it and make sure it handles argument that you are passing from view.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$route['read_inquiry/(:any)'] = 'dashboard/read_inquiry';
```

or:

```
$route['read_inquiry/(:num)'] = 'dashboard/read_inquiry/$1';
```

detailed explanation here:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html